# Invalid hook call error when trying to use React-pro-sidebar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sidebar

I'm trying to use the react-pro-sidebar package

```
https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar
```

However I keep on getting the invalid hook call error

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

For some context, I'm using react with react-router for navigation between pages. I wanted to create a sidebar and populate the menu items with react-router links, but that wasn't working out. Below is what I have:

```
import React from 'react'
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem, SubMenu } from 'react-pro-sidebar';

const fun = <ProSidebar>
    <Menu iconShape="square">
        <MenuItem>Dashboard</MenuItem>
        <SubMenu title="Components">
            <MenuItem>Component 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Component 2</MenuItem>
        </SubMenu>
    </Menu>
</ProSidebar>; 


const SideBarDashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        {fun}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SideBarDashboard;
```

And an alternative approach that didn't work out either:

```
const fun = () => { <ProSidebar>
    <Menu iconShape="square">
        <MenuItem>Dashboard</MenuItem>
        <SubMenu title="Components">
            <MenuItem>Component 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Component 2</MenuItem>
        </SubMenu>
    </Menu>
</ProSidebar>; }


const SideBarDashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>{fun}</div>
  )
}
```

And here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "contact-router",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update question to include your package.json file so we can see what versions you possibly have installed? If possible could you also try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this error for us to inspect and debug live? I think it's likely an incorrect version dependency, but if it's in a 3rd-party library there might not be much you could do. What debugging steps have you taken to isolate where the issue is coming from?

Comment: I included the package.json file, as for the demo I'm not sure what to give, I just started this out today to see how one could use that particular package to make sidebars

Comment: If `ProSidebar` is trying to run hooks,  I wonder if that needs to be inlined or as a function.  Have you tried not using `fun` but just putting the `ProSidebar` inline in your SideBarDashboard component?  or defining it as a function like `const fun = () => (<ProSidebar> ... </ProSidebar>)`

Comment: I have tried putting it inline at first, trying the function approach results in the following error: ```Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/invalid-hook-call-error-when-trying-to-use-react-pro-sidebar-5kixrc) and matched the npm package versions and can't reproduce the error. Have you tried killing all code-watchers/hot-reloaders and restarting the app from scratch, `npm start`? If issue persists then please try creating a codesandbox of your own that reproduces the error for us to inspect and debug.

Comment: @DrewReese truth be told when I tried making recreating my problem in codesandbox I have no issues, so I have no idea what to make of things, I'll link the codesandbox below

Comment: ```https://codesandbox.io/s/invalid-hook-call-error-when-trying-to-use-react-pro-sidebar-forked-nn8dow?file=/src/App.js```

Comment: I see. Without a reproducible example it's difficult for anyone to really help here. Have you tried running your code in a different browser? On a different machine? etc...?

Comment: @DrewReese so I figured out my problem, i had installed the package into the wrong folder so it was never mentioned in the package.json... have to be more careful in the future haha

Comment: Ooof, super obvious now looking back at your package.json file and seeing it missing from it. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

As a 'solved my own answer', my problem was that I installed the package into the wrong folder so it was never included in my package.json